# Continuing Counting Across Subs

Tags: excel, vba

I am running my main sub which I want to pause every 5 loops for 10 seconds. My code appears to work, but the problem I am facing is that my counting variables (namely j, i, and n) reset their counts after the pause sub is run.

Is there an effective way of passing keeping the current counts after running the sub that sits within the sub?

```
Sub DataPopulation()
Dim count As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Total As Long
Dim j As Integer
i = 6
n = 7
Total = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For j = 7 To Total
If j Mod 5 = 0 Then
    Call Application.OnTime(Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "DataPopulation")
    Exit Sub
End If
Range("B" & i & ":" & "FO" & i).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & i & ":" & "FO"     &n    ),Type:=xlFillDefault
n = n + 1
i = i + 1
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: you can use `static` to declare variables that 'remember' their previous values

Comment: @Jochen - I've tried Static n As Integer, Static i As Integer, Static Total As Integer, Static j As Integer declared at the beginning of the DataPopulation sub, but this still seems to have the same effect

Comment: you have to change your program logic a little. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. If you got question, just ask.

```
Sub DataPopulation()
Static I As Integer
Dim Total As Long
Dim j As Integer

Total = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
If I = 0 Or I >= Total Then I = 6


For j = 1 To 10
    If I >= Total Then Exit Sub
    Range("B" & I & ":" & "FO" & I).AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & I & ":" & "FO" & I + 1), Type:=xlFillDefault
    I = I + 1
Next j
Call Application.OnTime(Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "DataPopulation")
End Sub
```

Comment: This code doesn't appear to do anything. Perhaps i'm executing it incorrectly but the code doesn't appear to make any changes on the sheet

Comment: The code autofills rows from 'B' to 'FO' starting from row 6, 10 times a single row, pausees 10 secs, next 10 rows

Comment: the 'work-code' is the same autofil you used in your original code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Application.Wait` function, instead of `Application.OnTime`.

Your code would look like:

```
Sub DataPopulation()
Dim count As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Total As Long
Dim j As Integer
i = 6
n = 7
Total = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For j = 7 To Total
If j Mod 5 = 0 Then
    Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
    Exit Sub
End If
Range("B" & i & ":" & "FO" & i).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & i & ":" & "FO"     &n    ),Type:=xlFillDefault
n = n + 1
i = i + 1
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: As I'm using this with Bloomberg, there is a known problem of the data requests not being made with Application.Wait as far as I'm aware

Comment: Application.wait stops eveything in excel.